# Mounting smb share on Ubuntu 10.10 fails

Tags: ubuntu, mount, smb

Trying to mount a smb share in Ubuntu 10.10 just fails :(.

I have used the following command:

> sudo mount -t cifs //share /mnt/smb/

Looking inside kernel error messages I can see this:

> [11502.143801] CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22

Comment: I have the feeling that I have used the wrong site :D. Can someone migrate this to superuser.com?

Comment: It will get migrated automatically as soon as it receives enough close votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the server name? You need to reference the share by IP address.

```
sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.1/SharedFolder /mnt/smb
```

If you want to use dns, you'll need to install **mount.cifs** which is included in the package **cifs-utils**.